# com.google.api.services.drive.model.File.getName() returns null

Tags: google-drive-api

The following code is used to upload a file to Google Drive:

```
java.io.File fileData = new java.io.File(this.getFileStreamPath("foo.dat").getPath());
FileContent fileContent = new FileContent("file/binary", fileData);
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = googleDriveService.files().create(fileMetadata, fileContent)
                                        .setFields("id")
                                        .execute();
```

The upload works flawlessly (it can be verified easily by watching Google Drive). However, `file.getName()` returns null. I expect it to return "foo.dat". I do see uploaded file foo.dat on Google Drive.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which fields will be returned after the Request is performed:

Change `.setFields("id")` to:

- `.setFields("*")` to get all fields which will include `name`
- `.setFields("id, name")` to get the `file Id` and `name` in the variable `file`.

---

#### Reference:

- Fields parameter in [files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get#parameters).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer.